# Save specific xml using word macro

Tags: xml, vba, ms-word, save, acrobat

I have got a problem with saving xml via word macro. I have fill-in form created in adobe acrobat reader with functionality to export data. Everything is fine as long as I edit xml exported via this form, using for example notepad.

I came up with an idea to make my work little easier and created macro in ms word. I analized structure of this xml so I could easily manipulate with data I needed. Problem is when I create xml it does not let me import it. Content is excacly the same but technique is different. Exported via adobe acrobat reader and edited - it's ok; created differently - getting error like this:

> Xml parsing error: not well-formed (invalid token) (error code 4),
>   line 115, column 3 of file *path to my file*

I thought it could be a problem with ms word xml but when I save it to txt and later change extension to xml does not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by file coding. I changed it and now it works ok.